# Windows 10 record DVR not working with GTX 750 TI

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I recently bought an Nvidia Gforce GTX 750 TI graphics card. I installed it and ran all the driver updates through windows and the Nvidia update utility.

When I attempt to record through the built-in DVR system in Windows 10, I receive an error message claiming my graphics card doesn't meet the requirements and a link to (https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/system-requirements/pc-hardware-requirements-for-game-dvr). My card should be supported. Why isn't it working?

Thanks.

Comment: Your card isn't listed in that article.

Comment: @rane I know but it says "gforce 600 series or later but not...", Mine is a 700 series.

Comment: ah, you're right, I misread

Comment: It seems you should have NvEnc,  but not an updated version that supports HEVC https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/894633/gtx-750-ti-nvenc-hevc/. Can you use Nvidia GeForce Experience program to record video instead or lower the video setting in the Microsoft recorder?

Comment: The DVR settings are already at the lowest frame rate (30fps) and resolution. I'll try the nvidia experience program. I find this surprising. This card could easily record DVR. It's much more powerful than the HD graphics in my 3rd generation i5. My HD graphics recorded the DVR perfectly.

Comment: @mokubai The nvidia experience program doesn't work for recording either.

Comment: I found a free third party solution which works well (https://obsproject.com/).